# code works when it's not in a function, error when used in a function

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried to run my code and it ran perfectly, but when I put it in a function, it gives my the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function checkzip() in /Users/... line
>   3

here's the code inside the function checkzip

```php
            $zip = readline('customer zipcode: ');

            checkzip($dbc, $zip);

         function checkzip($dbc, $zip){

                $userzip = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT zip FROM zipcodes WHERE zip LIKE '$zip'");
                $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($userzip);

                if ($num_rows == 0){
                    echo "zip doesn't exist";
                    $city = readline('enter city name: ');
                    $zipcity = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO zipcodes (zip, city) VALUES('$zip', '$city') ");
                    echo "zip created. ";
                }};
```

I tried to use global but it didn't work, I got the same error.

knowing that this simple code with user inputs inside the a function works, I can't figure out why the code above doesn't:

```php
    $user1 = readline('num1: ');
    $user2 = readline('num2: ');

func($user1, $user2);


function func($user1, $user2) {
    echo " $user1 * $user2 ";
};
```

Comment: Make sure you have no typo in the `checkzip` function name.

Comment: Are you defining `checkzip` inside an `if` or another function?

Comment: @Barmar I copied it soI'm sure there's no typo. and no I'm not.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with what's inside the function. It can't find the function definition at all.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are calling the function before defining it.

Edit: I know the PHP manual says it doesn't matter however I found out the hard way that in some cases it does matter... Why? who the hell knows? I'm assuming that people who down voted my answer are PHP programmes hence they should know how quirky is PHP.

Comment: I never thought this would be the reason! it worked when I defined the function then called it! Thanks

Comment: This does not matter in PHP. You could have all your functions at the end of the executable file. When PHP parses the files it will pick up at the function definitions and know how to reference them at run time.

Comment: This is what I was thinking! it's weird when I cut the call and placed it after the function definition it worked for some reason

Comment: @wbur probably a syntax problem, like open brackets or similar.

Comment: Stackoverflow is the only place where you solve one's problem and get down voted... You are welcome.

Comment: @TonyMorello Sometimes that's the way it works.  Perhaps the act of moving the code caused the OP to inadvertently fix whatever syntax or code structure issue was truly the root cause (Honestly the original question did not contain enough code context to truly understand what the root problem was). PHP is not quirky with regards to how functions are accessed though.  There was some valid reason as to why the function was considered to be undefined and moving it before the calling code was not the "true" solution. Thus the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are putting your code in another function. I tried this and got the same error message. Otherwise, no error occurs.